# is there an alternative for addforce if i want use kinematic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a pong game but my ball isn't flying like I want. My ball is getting impacted from gravity. I know i need to set the body type from `dynamic` to `kinematic` but if I use `kinematic`, my ball isnt moving anymore because my ball flys with `addforce`. Which force can I use so that I can `kinematic` use?

```
public class BallPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody2D rbBall;
public float SpeedX = 10.0f;
public float SpeedY = 5.0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    rbBall.AddForce(new Vector2(SpeedX, SpeedY)); // my ball is flying
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collisionInfo) // collision for the walls
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "wall")
    {
        SpeedX = -SpeedX;
        SpeedY = -SpeedY;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the setting of `Use Gravity` on the `Rigidbody` component of your ball?

Comment: I am using `rigidbody2D` so there is no `Use Gravity` mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `useGravity` in `RigidBody2D` but you can simply leave `IsKinematic` disabled and rather also disable it's [`gravityScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html)

```
private void Start()
{
    rbBall.gravityScale = 0;
}
```

this has the same effect as disabling `useGravity` on a `RigidBody`. Especially in the context of your question I really like the note

> it may be easier to implement a flying character by turning off its gravity rather than simulating the forces that keep it aloft.

;)

---

or alternatively disable gravity for the entire scene/project using [`Physics2D.gravity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-gravity.html)

```
private void Start()
{
    Physics2D.gravity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

---

To the question itself

> Is there an alternative for addforce if I want use kinematic?

No and yes...

From [`RigidBody2D.isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-isKinematic.html)

> Should this rigidbody be taken out of physics control?
>
> If this property is set to true then the rigidbody will stop reacting to collisions and applied forces. This can be useful when an object should usually be controlled "kinematically" (ie, non-physically) but then sometimes needs physics for realism. For example, a human character is usually not implemented using physics but may sometimes be thrown through the air and collide with objects as the result of an impact or explosion.

Or also from [`Rigidbody.isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)

> If `isKinematic` is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore. The rigidbody will be under full control of animation or script control by changing `transform.position`.

So simply use the

```
transform.position = ...
```

as usual.

---

For having something similar to `AddForce` you could store a local speed vector and add more speed like

```
// public so you can also configure 
// it in the inspector or set it from another script
public Vector2 speed;

public void AddForce(Vector2 force)
{
    speed += force;
}

private void Update()
{
    transform.position += speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

However in your case you don't want to add speed each frame but probably only set a certain speed once at start and on collisions.

Comment: thanks hugo, i needed to adapt some things but it worked, <3